# Android Studio Image Asset Editor missing after update

Tags: flutter, dart

[Apologies if this is the wrong forum to be asking this question] At some recent point, probably after an update, I realized the Image Asset editor in my Android Studio was missing. If I right click an asset the popup menu choice New > Image Asset is not present.

Any ideas how to get it back?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? Experiencing the same issue in Android Studo 3.5.1